# Use pycurl to get response from server

Tags: python, curl, dbpedia, pycurl, spotlight-dbpedia

```
def curlDBPedia(DB_url):
    data = json.dumps({"text":"President Obama called Wednesday on Congress to extend a tax break for students included in last year's economic stimulus package, arguing that the policy provides more generous assistance.",
    "confidence": "0.2", "support": "20"
    })
    c = pycurl.Curl()
    c.setopt(pycurl.URL, DB_url)
    c.setopt(pycurl.POST, 1)
    c.setopt(pycurl.POSTFIELDS, data)
    c.perform()
curlDBPedia("http://spotlight.dbpedia.org/rest/annotate")
```

The program is given as above, but I can not get correct response from the server.
The error is:
)

> com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
>   com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
>   com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
>   com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:701)
>   .
>   .
>   .
>   .

This is only a snapshot of the error.

How can I fix it?

Comment: I'm a bit confused;  it looks like you've pasted Python code, but a java stacktrace.  Can you provide a bit more context?  UPDATE: after posting that URL into a browser (which will do a GET request, I realize), I see similar output.  The output isn't a stacktrace from *your* program, but the output from the server.  So something in the request needs to be different.

Comment: What does the start of the exception say? That's the important part, not the end.

Comment: It looks like the web server has some bugs.

Answer (score 3):

You could try this code ..

```
def curlDBPedia(DB_url):
        data = json.dumps({"text":"President Obama called Wednesday on Congress to extend a tax break for students included in last year's economic stimulus package, arguing that the policy provides more generous assistance.",
        "confidence": "0.2", "support": "20"
        })
        buffer = StringIO()
        c = pycurl.Curl()
        c.setopt(pycurl.URL, DB_url)
        c.setopt(pycurl.POST, 1)
        c.setopt(pycurl.POSTFIELDS, data)
        c.setopt(c.WRITEFUNCTION, buffer.write)
        c.perform()
        c.close()
        body = buffer.getvalue()#here we got the response data
    curlDBPedia("http://spotlight.dbpedia.org/rest/annotate")
```